# Git: Show list of commits during interactive rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I'm in the middle of an interactive rebase. Is there a command that shows the list of commits that were initially selected when I started the rebase?

Answer (score 10):

During the interactive rebase, git updates files in your `.git` directory under the sub-directory `rebase-merge` (the exact path has changed in various versions of git, as I recall; I'm looking at git 2.0.x behavior right now).

In that directory are the files `done` and `git-rebase-todo`.  These are not quite what you asked for: they're the finished parts and the not-yet-done parts, not the "pick" commands that were presented to you initially, nor necessarily the commands you've gone with (if you skipped some).  There's also a `git-rebase-todo.backup`, which contains what was in the "todo" list after you edited it.  I'm not sure if you wanted the complete list of revs or the list you chose at the time you exited the editor, but if it's the latter, the backup file is the right thing.

There is also a reference named `ORIG_HEAD` that points to the tip of the (original) branch that is being rebased, and `.git/rebase-merge/head-name` which contains the name of the branch (and the branch is not moved until the rebase is complete).  You could use this, plus some of the other files, to reconstruct the originally-offered "pick" list.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Git 2.3.0 (February 2015) will display the number of "todo" during an interactive rebase.

See [commit 97f05f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97f05f43dc73f2855eb4c6acd1ea49d6d6bc4bce) by [Onno Kortmann (`onnokort`)](https://github.com/onnokort)

> #### Show number of `TODO` items for interactive rebase
>
> During '`rebase -i`', one wrong edit in a long rebase session might inadvertently drop commits/items.
>   This change shows the total number of `TODO` items in the comments after the
>   list.
>   After performing the rebase edit, total item counts can be compared to make sure that no changes have been lost in the edit.

The [`git-rebase--interactive.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/97f05f43dc73f2855eb4c6acd1ea49d6d6bc4bce/git-rebase--interactive.sh#L1034-L1038) now includes (using [`git stripspace`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stripspace)):

```
todocount=$(git stripspace --strip-comments <"$todo" | wc -l)
cat >>"$todo" <<EOF
$comment_char Rebase $shortrevisions onto $shortonto ($todocount TODO item(s))
```

---

Note that with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), an interactive rebase will be able to produce the todo list with a single-letter command names (if the  configuration variable `rebase.abbreviateCommands` is set).

See [commit 1795993](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1795993488bef1b48e4224db096e9d12df075db2), [commit d8ae6c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8ae6c84da52a210e84b3734bb93c575638236d3), [commit 0cce4a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cce4a2756eb2c66544615e5ccd74671afb33256), [commit 313a48e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/313a48eaca58ecd170bef9e6a5a55001c7511f08), [commit d80fc29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d80fc29367a6cf92792db6e3d1b5ce2ae2d81de8), [commit 8dccc7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8dccc7a6b2deb05783ea5d57b53548dab32d99ae) (05 Dec 2017), and [commit 7dcbb3c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7dcbb3cb6d4f06ff305e5a18dba873261d3fa5d3), [commit f3b633d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3b633dad4cc54c7cdaa007e97d00b2c935c9a90), [commit 946a9f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/946a9f20b46b6cf8fbfbcc69ed97182f8696bb8d) (03 Dec 2017) by [Liam Beguin (`Liambeguin`)](https://github.com/Liambeguin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0da2ba4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0da2ba4880f971de2782f2d4cfcd68f9148d2860), 27 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### `rebase -i`: learn to abbreviate command names
>
> `git rebase -i` already know how to interpret single-letter command
>   names.
>   Teach it to generate the todo list with these same abbreviated
>   names.

The [`git rebase` config man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d8ae6c84da52a210e84b3734bb93c575638236d3/Documentation/rebase-config.txt#L34-L52) will read:

> ```
> rebase.abbreviateCommands::
> ```
>
> If set to true, `git rebase` will use abbreviated command names in the todo list resulting in something like this:
>
> ```
> -------------------------------------------
>     p deadbee The oneline of the commit
>     p fa1afe1 The oneline of the next commit
>     ...
> -------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> -------------------------------------------
>     pick deadbee The oneline of the commit
>     pick fa1afe1 The oneline of the next commit
>     ...
> -------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Defaults to `false`.

---

Note that Git 2.21 (Q1 2019) makes "`git stripspace`" usable *outside* a git repository, even in ["`-s`" or "`-c`" mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stripspace#_options).

> ### `stripspace`: allow `-s`/`-c` *outside* git repository
>
> [v2.11.0-rc3~3^2~1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92068ae8bf5711b683a0dbeef75d76f56ead5590) (`stripspace`: respect repository config, 2016-11-21, Git v2.11.0-rc3) improved `stripspace --strip-comments` / `--commentlines` by teaching them to read repository config, but it went a little too far: when running `stripspace` outside any repository, the result is
>
> ```
> $ git stripspace --strip-comments <test-input
>  fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /tmp)
> ```
>
> That makes experimenting with the stripspace command unnecessarily fussy.
>   Fix it by discovering the `git` directory gently, as intended all along.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), allow the `rebase.missingCommitsCheck` configuration to kick in when "`rebase --edit-todo`" and "`rebase --continue`" restarts the procedure.

See [commit 5a5445d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5445d8788058c6d038f5f4072316db0d250eeb), [commit 1da5874](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1da5874c1b283862f8252a2f5f2f8d4afe86346a) (28 Jan 2020) by [Alban Gruin (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4dbeecb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dbeecba27983a86c17383280856bbbe385ceb8d), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase-interactive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5445d8788058c6d038f5f4072316db0d250eeb): warn if commit is dropped with `rebase --edit-todo`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alban Gruin</sup>
>
> When set to "warn" or "error", `rebase.missingCommitsCheck` would make `rebase -i` warn if the user removed commits from the `todo` list to prevent mistakes.
>
> Unfortunately, `rebase --edit-todo` and `rebase --continue` don't take it into account.
>
> This adds the ability for `rebase --edit-todo` and `rebase --continue' to check if commits were dropped by the user.
>
> As both `edit_todo_list()` and `complete_action()` parse the `todo` list and check for dropped commits, the code doing so in the latter is removed to reduce duplication. `edit_todo_list_advice` is removed from [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a5445d8788058c6d038f5f4072316db0d250eeb/sequencer.c) as it is no longer used there.
>
> This changes when a backup of the `todo` list is made.
>
> Until now, it was saved only once, before the initial edit.
>
> Now, it is also made if the original todo list has no errors or no dropped commits.
>
> Thus, the backup should be error-free.
>
> Without this, `sequencer_continue()` (`rebase --continue`) could only compare the current `todo` list against the original, unedited list.
>
> Before this change, this file was only used by `edit_todo_list()` and `rebase -p` to create the backup before the initial edit, and `check_todo_list_from_file()`, only used by `rebase -p` to check for dropped commits after its own initial edit.
>
> If the edited list has an error, a file, `dropped`, is created to report the issue.
>
> Otherwise, it is deleted.
>
> Usually, the edited list is compared against the list before editing, but if this file exists, it will be compared to the backup.
>
> Also, if the file exists, `sequencer_continue()` checks the list for dropped commits.
>
> If the check was performed every time, it would fail when resuming a rebase after resolving a conflict, as the backup will contain commits that were picked, but they will not be in the new list.
>
> It's safe to ignore this check if `dropped` does not exist, because that means that no errors were found at the last edition, so any missing commits here have already been picked.
>
> Five tests are added to t3404.
>
> The tests for `rebase.missingCommitsCheck = warn' and`rebase.missingCommitsCheck = error' have a similar structure.
>
> - First, we start a rebase with an incorrect command on the first line.
> - Then, we edit the `todo` list, removing the first and the last lines.
>     This demonstrates that `--edit-todo` notices dropped commits, but not when the command is incorrect.
> - Then, we restore the original `todo` list, and edit it to remove the last line.
>     This demonstrates that if we add a commit after the initial edit, then remove it, `--edit-todo` will notice that it has been dropped.
> - Then, the actual rebase takes place.
> - In the third test, it is also checked that `--continue` will refuse to resume the rebase if commits were dropped.
> - The fourth test checks that no errors are raised when resuming a rebase after resolving a conflict,
> - the fifth checks that no errors are raised when editing the `todo` list after pausing the rebase.