# routing inside code sandbox, failing due to withRouter

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

When I hit submit button I need to redirect to this page pageOne, so I googled and found a react router and used this line `this.props.history.push("/anotherPage");`, but its not redirecting.
Its throwing an error Invariant failed: `You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>`
Can you tell me how to fix it.
Providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-n9o7s

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

anotherPage = () => {
  console.log("redictToStepper --->");
  this.props.history.push("/anotherPage");
};

render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;
  const { checkBoxvalues } = this.state;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>increase when I hit submit button</div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(RadioButtonsGroup));
```

Comment: You need a <Router> component, but I also think you're using withRouter too high in your application. Abstract the form in demo down out to another component and build your routes at the level of demo. Look at the sample at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your most-outer component using `BrowserRouter`, so it will provided the needed props and behavior to its children.

On your `index.js` replace your render with:

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Demo} />
    <Route exact path="/anotherPage" component={PageOne} />
  </BrowserRouter>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

To render your components inside each route, please refer to [react router documentation](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router).

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...I updated the code but still its not showing the div in another page. Can you tell me how to fix it https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-n9o7s

Comment: You need to have a `<Route />` for each route you want to load and pass which component should be rendered via props. Please, refer to https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router to learn about it, stackoverflow should be used to remove on point doubts and problems, can't teach that to you here.

Comment: Hey I updated the code with Route but still its not working...can you tell me how to fix it `<Route exact path="/pageOne" component={PageOne} />` providing my sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-n9o7s

Comment: <BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Demo} />
    <Route exact path="/anotherPage" component={PageOne} />
  </BrowserRouter>

This will allow you to render the different components for different routes. Please, if initial question is already answered, accept it. For further information regarding routes, refer to their documentation, it's pretty good.